# VBA - populate cell from different sheet on mouse click

Tags: vba, onclick, automation

The problem I am facing is, I require a cell to autopopulate from a cell reference in a different sheet within the same workbook when the user clicks the cell.

E.g. 
1) User clicks A1 on sheet 1
2) Cell A2 on sheet 1 populates with value from cell A1 in sheet 2

I need this function to span approximatly 80+ references, in other words I have a list of over 80 project names in sheet 1 a1= projectname 1 a2= projectname2 and so on.
sheet 2 has all of the project descriptions...a1 project1 descroption..a2 project2 description and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

In the sheet you are selecting add the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
   If Target.column = 1 Then
     ... do something
   End If
End Sub
```

This method gets called anytime you select a new cell.